# divide a column of lists by numbers in another column

Tags: r, apply, lapply

Hi there I have this data frame (`test`) and I want to divide every element in the list (`AO`) by a value in another column (`DP`):

```
df <- structure(list(DP = c("572", "594", "625", "594", "537", "513"
), AO2 = list(list(c(2, 2)), list(c(2, 2, 2)), list(c(4, 4)), 
    list(c(3, 2, 2, 2, 3)), list(c(2, 2)), list(c(2, 2)))), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

df
```

I would like to create a new column in `df` where each value of the list is divided by the value in `df$DP` of the same row.

[image]

I have tried using mapply but it didn't work. Any idea?

```
test$AO2_DP <- mapply(FUN = `/`, list(as.numeric(unlist(test$AO2))), as.numeric(test$DP), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

Comment: Please, share a sample of your data with `dput`

Answer (score 1):

Base R option using `Map` -

```
df$result <- Map(`/`, unlist(df$AO2, recursive = FALSE),df$DP)
df

#    DP       AO2                                                      result
#1: 572 <list[1]>                                     0.003496503,0.003496503
#2: 594 <list[1]>                         0.003367003,0.003367003,0.003367003
#3: 625 <list[1]>                                               0.0064,0.0064
#4: 594 <list[1]> 0.005050505,0.003367003,0.003367003,0.003367003,0.005050505
#5: 537 <list[1]>                                     0.003724395,0.003724395
#6: 513 <list[1]>                                     0.003898635,0.003898635
```

If `DP` value is character in your real data turn it to numeric first by `df$DP <- as.numeric(df$DP)` before applying the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the column of lists can be nested you can use `rapply` to go to each element and make the division.

```
df$AO2_DP <- Map(function(x, y) rapply(x, function(z) z/y, how="replace"),
   df$AO2, as.numeric(df$DP))

df
#   DP           AO2                                                          AO2_DP
#1 572          2, 2                                        0.003496503, 0.003496503
#2 594       2, 2, 2                           0.003367003, 0.003367003, 0.003367003
#3 625          4, 4                                                  0.0064, 0.0064
#4 594 3, 2, 2, 2, 3 0.005050505, 0.003367003, 0.003367003, 0.003367003, 0.005050505
#5 537          2, 2                                        0.003724395, 0.003724395
#6 513          2, 2                                        0.003898635, 0.003898635
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `rowwise` and `sapply` will help

```
test %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(DP = as.numeric(DP)) %>%
  mutate(AO2_DP = list(sapply(AO2, function(x) x/DP)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's `dplyr` solution using your original idea but modified

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(AO2_DP = list(mapply(FUN = "/", list(as.numeric(unlist(AO2))), as.numeric(DP), SIMPLIFY = FALSE))) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
#>    DP           AO2
#> 1 572          2, 2
#> 2 594       2, 2, 2
#> 3 625          4, 4
#> 4 594 3, 2, 2, 2, 3
#> 5 537          2, 2
#> 6 513          2, 2
#>                                                            AO2_DP
#> 1                                        0.003496503, 0.003496503
#> 2                           0.003367003, 0.003367003, 0.003367003
#> 3                                                  0.0064, 0.0064
#> 4 0.005050505, 0.003367003, 0.003367003, 0.003367003, 0.005050505
#> 5                                        0.003724395, 0.003724395
#> 6                                        0.003898635, 0.003898635
```

I added a quotation mark to the `FUN` of your `mapply()`, and then to perform the row-wise operation I use `rowwise()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
  unnest(AO2) %>%
  mutate(DP = as.numeric(DP),
         res = map2(.x = AO2, .y = DP, .f = ~ .x / .y))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below

```
transform(
  df,
  AO2_DP = Map("/", unlist(AO2, recursive = FALSE), as.numeric(DP))
)
```

which gives

```
    DP       AO2                                                      AO2_DP
1: 572 <list[1]>                                     0.003496503,0.003496503
2: 594 <list[1]>                         0.003367003,0.003367003,0.003367003
3: 625 <list[1]>                                               0.0064,0.0064
4: 594 <list[1]> 0.005050505,0.003367003,0.003367003,0.003367003,0.005050505
5: 537 <list[1]>                                     0.003724395,0.003724395
6: 513 <list[1]>                                     0.003898635,0.003898635
```